# Using Jekyll for Website without Blog

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'd like to use Jekyll for my website, but I can't figure out how to set it up. All of the documentation I've seen shows how to use Jekyll to set up a blog. I just want to write Markdown and have Jekyll convert it to a website.

I understand that this question is a bit vague and the terminology may not be perfectly accurate. I'm new to creating a website and I don't want to learn HTML.

(Disclosure: My website will be for a project on GitHub.)

Comment: Jekyll now has official tutorials on their site. While this one is about converting existing HTML sites, there's a bunch of info about using Markdown and Jekyll in general you might find useful. https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/convert-site-to-jekyll/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's four types of document that you can find in a Jekyll site :

- **[Static files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/)** like js, css or even html page. They don't have a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/), are simply copied at generation time and can be found in the `site.static_files` hash,
- **[posts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/)** they are located in `_posts` folder, have a front matter and can be found in the `site.posts` hash by liquid,
- **[pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/)** they can be anywhere in your folder structure, have a front matter and can be found in the site.pages hash by liquid,
- **[collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/)** that are more elaborated pieces of datas with a front matter and can be found in `site.collections` hash by liquid.

You can choose to use any of them. If you don't want to use posts, just remove or empty the `_posts` folder and just use pages.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is write markdown and have that generate a single page for a project, consider using the [GH-pages automatic generator](https://pages.github.com/).

In step 3 you write the content for your page in Github-flavoured Markdown and then select a layout to publish it in.
[image: GH-pages screenshot]